# Aumentar y disminuir numero de value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input con un value, quiero que aumente y disminuya según que botón se de click, ya que quiero incluirlo en un carrito de compras.

```
<button id='aumentar'>+</button>
<button id='disminuir'>-</button>

<input type='text' value='1'>
```

Comment: Y que has intentado? Tienes algun problema en especifico?

Answer (score 2):

Un pequeño escript, espero te funcione :)

```js
var inicio = 0; //se inicializa una variable en 0

function aumentar(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id aumentar

var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value = ++inicio; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se incrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
}

function disminuir(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id disminuir

var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value = --inicio; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se decrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
}
```

```html
<button id='aumentar' onclick="aumentar()">+</button>
<button id='disminuir' onclick="disminuir()">-</button>

<input type='text' id="cantidad" value="0">
```

Comment: Una explicación no estaría de más, responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: listo @anonimo ya comente en el código que hace, aunque no tiene mucha ciencia.

Answer (score 1):

Con una función de javascript podrías aumentar el valor de tu contador:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var valor=0;
function carrito(boton){
    var contador = document.getElementById("contador").value;
    if (boton.value=='aumentar') {
        valor++
    }else{
        valor--
    }
    document.getElementById("contador").textContent = valor;
}

</script>
<button id='aumentar' onclick="carrito(this)" value="aumentar">+</button>
<button id='disminuir' onclick="carrito(this)" value="disminuir">-</button>

<p id='contador' value=""></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como base el ejemplo de Vick Muñoz se puede controlar el mínimo y máximo alertando cuando se llegue a los límites. Adicional, puedes colocar dígitos en el campo de texto y a partir de ese agregar o restar. Igual valida que no coloques números fuera de los límites permitidos

```js
var max = 100;
var min = 1;

//funcion para validar cambio manual en el campo de texto
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
  if (x > max || x < min) {
    alert('Valor no aceptado');
    $('#cantidad').val(min);
    $('#cantidad').trigger('change');
    return false;
  }
  $('#pbi_reiterado').val();
  $('#pbi_reiterado').trigger('change');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}

//funciones incremento
function aumentar() { // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id aumentar

  var inicio = $("#cantidad").val();
  var incrementado = ++inicio;

  if (incrementado > max) {
    alert('Máximo permitido: ' + max);
    return false;
  }
  var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value = incrementado; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se incrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
}

//funciones decremento
function disminuir() { // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id disminuir
  var inicio = $("#cantidad").val();

  var decrementado = --inicio;
  if (decrementado < min) {
    alert('Mínimo permitido: ' + min);
    return false;
  }
  var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value = decrementado; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se decrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='disminuir' onclick="disminuir()">-</button>
<input type='text' id="cantidad" value="1" onchange="myFunction()">
<button id='aumentar' onclick="aumentar()">+</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Aquí un ejemplo con lo solicitado:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
    
    <button id="myBtn"  onclick="contador++;myFunction()">Aumentar</button>
    <button id="myBtn2" onclick="contador--;myFunction()">Disminuir</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    var contador = 0;
    
    function myFunction(tipo) {
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myText").value);
        x = x + contador;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```